# Property 'vis' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, tsx

**Tech**: React-Native

**DesiredResult**: I desire `this.state.vis` to be interpretable (as a boolean). This should be initialized to `true`, however, on a button click the state must be set to `false` making visibility false.

**Bug**: Located in the if-condition under render. This line of code does not recognize `this.state.vis` (only `this.props.vis`)

```
class ModalSectionCard extends React.Component <{vis:boolean,cardText:string}>{
  
  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      vis: this.props.vis
    };
  }

  
  render(){
    if (this.state.vis){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({vis:false})}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:"#333366"}}>
          <ModalSecCard  >
            <Text style={{color:"#fff"}}>{this.props.cardText}</Text>
          </ModalSecCard>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    } else{
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Used `let [visOpen, setVisOpen] = React.useState(true);` and `onPress={()=> setVisOpen(false)}` after changing the component to a function.

Relevant source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html